# How to make a list of files in a folder and paste each of line from this list into *.plist via Terminal?

Tags: ios, bash, command-line, terminal

I have some files in a folder (with *.m4r extension)
and I need to copy each name of them to another one (with *.plist extension).

For example,

```
Folder=/Library/Ringtones
```

Files in that folder:

```
 - name_of_first_file.m4r
 - name_of_second_file.m4r
 - name_of_third_file.m4r
```

Plist (where we should add this files' names):

```
Plist=/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ToneKit.framework/TKRingtones.plist
```

that's what I need to have at the end in this plist file:

```
<string>system:name_of_first_file</string>
<string>system:name_of_second_file</string>
<string>system:name_of_third_file</string>
```

Also I don't know how many files in **Folder**.
There can be 1 or 2 in it, or even 100!

Could you please tell me how I can do that using bash in Terminal!
Thank you!

---

### ANSWER to **John1024**

This code works. Thanks

```
     #!/bin/bash
     cd /Library/Ringtones
     Plist="/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ToneKit.framework/TKRingtones.plist"
     for file in *.m4r; do printf '<string>system:%s</string>\n' "$file" ; done >>"$Plist"
     exit 0
```

---

### I've got one more question.

**1** Here's the stock plist TKRingtones.plist (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ToneKit.framework/)

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
     <plist version="1.0">
     <dict>
        <key>classic</key>
        <array>
            <string>system:unlock</string>
            <string>system:Alarm</string>
            <string>system:Ascending</string>
        </array>
        <key>modern</key>
        <array>
            <string>system:Apex</string>
            <string>system:Beacon</string>
        </array>
        <key>sort</key>
        <true/>
     </dict>
     </plist>
```

How can I make the script (that you suggested) paste the strings after **array**?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>classic</key>
        <array>
    <string>system:NAME_OF_FIRST_FILE</string> <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<ADD HERE 
    <string>system:NAME_OF_SECONDS_FILE</string> <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<ADD HERE
    <string>system:NAME_OF_THIRD_FILE</string> <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<ADD HERE
            <string>system:unlock</string>
            <string>system:Alarm</string>
            <string>system:Ascending</string>
        </array>
        <key>modern</key>
        <array>
            <string>system:Apex</string>
            <string>system:Beacon</string>
        </array>
        <key>sort</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    </plist>
```

Comment: You need to run John1024's script in the folder that contains the .m4r files. So change the `file="/Library/Ringtones"` line to `cd /Library/Ringtones`

Comment: ok, it works! Thanks! I one more thing left: how to paste all these line into the existing code (now this script breaks the code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In future, try to put all the information into your question from the start!

Printing a bunch of file names is relatively easy, inserting them at the correct location into an existing structured file is generally somewhat harder. I've chosen to use awk to do the insertion; it uses a variation of John1024's script internally to fetch the *.m4r file names.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Copy all .m4r filenames in "/Library/Ringtones" into the XML file $Plist
# Written by PM 2Ring 2014.11.09

Plist="/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ToneKit.framework/TKRingtones.plist"

cd "/Library/Ringtones"

#Make a backup of the current Plist
cp -p "$Plist" "$Plist.bak"

#Read from $Plist.bak, inserting new *.m4r names
# after the first <array> tag, and save to $Plist
awk '
$1 == "<array>" && ! copied {
    print
    while (( "for i in *.m4r; do echo ${i%.m4r}; done" | getline ) > 0)
        printf "    <string>system:%s</string>\n", $0
    copied = 1; next
}
{print}' "$Plist.bak" > "$Plist"

#View modified file to make sure it's correct
cat "$Plist"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for file in *.m4r; do printf '<string>system:%s</string>\n' "$file" ; done >>"$Plist"
```

The output looks like:

```
<string>system:name_of_first_file.m4r</string>
<string>system:name_of_second_file.m4r</string>
<string>system:name_of_third_file.m4r</string>
```

Explanation

- `for file in *.m4r; do`

  This starts a loop over every file in the current directory whose name ends with `.m4r`.

  This loop will work even if the file names includes spaces, tabs, or other difficult characters.
- `printf '<string>system:%s</string>\n' "$file"`

  This prints the string that we want that contains the file name.
- `done`

  This signals the end of the `for` loop.
- `>>"$Plist"`

  This causes all the output from this loop to be appended to the file named by the `Plist` shell variable.

#### Answer to Revised Question

This loop reads over the Plist file until it finds the `<array>` line and then writes out the new values (as we did above) and then finishes copying the Plist file:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
    printf "%s\n" "$line"
    case "$line" in
        *"<array>"*)
            for file in *.m4r
            do_
                printf '       <string>system:%s</string>\n' "$file"
            done
            ;;
    esac
done >"$Plist.tmp" <"$Plist"
mv "$Plist.tmp" "$Plist"
```

This should work in any POSIX shell.